# Best practices for building, version controlling, testing, archiving a Java project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, svn, ant, build, project

I would like to know the best practices in your mind to do things like those mentioned in this title.

Here is the background. I am involved in a personal Java project and hope to test, build, archive, and publish them systematically.  I am using Eclipse 3.7.  Since I am quite new to all those great tools that enhance productivity, like ANT, Maven, Svn, Git, etc, I am ready to pick up and learn any of them.

Comment: This is not a specific problem and the answers would be broad and certaintly open to opinion. Maybe this is best suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best advice is to learn how to build, test, and package your code **without Eclipse** first. Newbies can get confused because their IDE will do things for them without understanding why.

I personally prefer Gradle over Ant or Maven but it is newer and might be harder to find examples for. For an SCM I think subversion is easy to pick up but all the cool kids use Git and Github so you might want to learn them as it will only help you in the future.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html

Comment: Great advice! I loved the _without_ part

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, more and more project use maven as project packaging tool. It is convenient and help you to solve the dependency problem.

However, as you are new to the tools, I suggest you to use Ant first. In My opinion, it will be easier to use for beginner. I personally prefer to use Eclipse as development tools and Ant as build tools because Ant integrates well with Eclipse.

For source code version control, I suggest to use SVN. You could download convenient SVN client like Tortoise. http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Comment: +1 for Tortoise on Windows. If you use Win and SVN then tortoise is excellent. Also the Subclipse plugin for Eclipse is very high quality.

Comment: Does ANT go with Eclipse? Apparently, Eclipse has its built-in build process. Will I have to copy ANT's configurations to Eclipse's manually?

Comment: It's supported out of box, Ant is a first-class citizen in Eclipse IDE. Eclipse is even able to import a pre-existing Ant-driven project (works for simple projects)